# vim: highlight the title of viewport when in focus

Tags: vim, highlight, identification

When I have many files open in split viewports, it takes effort to identify the location of my focus. Even though I tried to work around this problem by highlight the cursor using `cursorline`, the highlight occurs in all respective viewports. So is there a way to  highlight the title of file when it is in selected? If not, Any solutions for easy-identification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Colorschemes usually have highlight definitions for `StatusLine` (current window) and `StatusLineNC` (other windows).

If your colorscheme doesn't, just find the line for `StatusLine`, duplicate it, change `StatusLine` into `StatusLineNC` and just put the colors you want.

For reference, here are the two relevant lines from the colorscheme that I use:

```
hi StatusLine term=bold,reverse cterm=bold ctermbg=101 ctermfg=16 gui=bold guibg=#808070 guifg=#000000
hi StatusLineNC term=reverse cterm=NONE ctermbg=59 ctermfg=16 gui=italic guibg=#404c4c guifg=#000000
```